# How to declare the fallback language on Android for TalkBack?

Tags: android, internationalization, accessibility, text-to-speech

I have an Android app that currently only has a fallback language, so all strings are in `res/values/strings.xml` and are in English. This works fine with TalkBack while the OS is also set to English. However, as soon as I change the OS language to anything other than English, TalkBack starts to speak those English words using the pronunciation of the OS language, which is weird and hard to understand.

How can I declare to the Android OS what the language of my fallback resources is so that TalkBack can choose the correct pronunciation to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know Talkback doesn't support auto language switching. Google TTS seems to do some auto switching based on non-latin characters these days, but for latin languages it just doesn't do anything except keep the phone language. So, I'm afraid there's nothing you can do to facilitate this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a strings.xml variation for english and leave it like this

```
<resources ...>
</resources>
```

Comment: Could you provide some source where you got this from? I tried creating a `res/values-en/strings.xml` with either your version, or self-closing `<resources />` and even one with a dummy `<string>` entry, but it didn't even result in a new `values-en` node in the `resources.asrc` file within the APK and thus the app on the device used TalkBack with the same broken pronunciation. I also tried copying `strings.xml` as-is, this resulted in it being included in `resources.asrc`, but TalkBack behaved the same, so I'm still looking for a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc：

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources

You can create different values-xx folder to support different languages!

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thanks, my problem is that the system doesn't know what language of the `values` folder (the one without any language codes, used for fallback) is. So if the user has a device set to a language the app doesn't support, TalkBack will try to read English with the pronunciation of the user's language. That's why I need to somehow communicate to the Android OS what the language of the fallback strings are.

Comment: @dnet     If the phone is set to another language, and there is a corresponding string in your folder, then the corresponding string will be used! But if not, the default English is used! No fallback settings!